# How can I find out what caused a paint event in Chrome's timeline frames tab

Tags: paint, google-chrome-devtools

When debugging slow paints in Chrome's Frames tab of the Timeline tab is it possible to figure out what was painted and what caused the paint? The paint events seem to only contain information about the paint time, the dimensions and the location.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it short - you should use a combination of **Show paint rectangles**, **Enable continuous page repainting** and the Timeline view. You find Show paint rectangles and Enable continuous page repainting under the **Rendering** tab in the Drawer.

There is more information on Google's Web Fundamentals webpage: [Simplify Paint Complexity and Reduce Paint Areas](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/simplify-paint-complexity-and-reduce-paint-areas#use_chrome_devtools_to_quickly_identify_paint_bottlenecks).